# What is the appropriate type of event for MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement> in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, mouseevent

What I'm trying to do is to close modal when clicking outside `div element`.
Please check my code first.

```js
// onClose function is setState(false) function.

import { useRef, useEffect } from 'hooks'
import { MouseEvent } from 'react'
import { MovieInfo } from 'types/movie'

interface Props {
  info: MovieInfo
  onClose: () => void
}

const Modal = ({ info, onClose }: Props) => {
  const modalRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
    }
  })

  const handleClickOutside = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    if (e.target.id === 'modal-container') onClose()
  }

  return (
    <div id='modal-container' ref={modalRef}>
      <div>
        <button type='button' onClick={onClose}>
          close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

This is my Component, so far, I was writing my code

```js
  const handleClickOutside = (e: any) => {
    if (e.target.id === 'modal-container') onClose()
  }
```

using any, so there seemed no problem at all.

However, after remove `e:any` and add `e: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>`,

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
    }
  })

  const handleClickOutside = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    if (e.target.id === 'modal-container') onClose()
  }
```

This useEffect hook and function make errors.

More precisely, two `handleClickOutside` are underlined, and `id` is underlined

and VScode gives an tooltip `No overload matches this call.` , `No overload matches this call.` for each.

If I'm missing something, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { MouseEvent } from 'react'
```

This type is for the events that react emits, eg when you use the `onClick` prop. Since you're subscribing directly to the document, you will be receiving a native dom event, not a react event, and so you need to use the dom event's type. It has the same name as the one from react, but you don't import it.

The fix is to delete the import, and remove the `<HTMLDivElement>` part (since the dom event isn't a generic). Also, the type information says that `e.target` might be null, so you'll either need to check for null or assert that it's not null.

```
const handleClickOutside = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    if (e.target?.id === 'modal-container') onClose()
}
```

Comment: I am getting error of `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`. Why does it happen?

Comment: `if ((e.target as HTMLDivElement).id === 'modal-container') onClose()` works. Thank you Nicholas !